# Jest mocking API calls returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm mocking an API call that my `<App/>` makes, but the `jest.mock` for the call is returning undefined.

Here's my App:

```
import './App.css';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getCount } from './api';

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    status: 'ok',
    count: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getCount().then((res) => setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, count: res })));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Sidebar state={state} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below is the API call (returning a Promise):

```
export function getCount() {
  return Promise.resolve(5);
}
```

Here is the test which tests the API call:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

jest.mock('./api', () => ({
  getCount: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(5)),
}));

test('renders app', () => {
  render(<App />);
});
```

Here is the error I get below. I'm not sure why the Jest mock, which is returning a Promise (just what the App expects to be returned) is still coming back as 'undefined'.
Any help is most appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example using https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the specifier that tells it you're mocking a module using ES6 import/exports:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

jest.mock('./api', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  getCount: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(5)),
}));

test('renders app', () => {
  render(<App />);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that wasn't it...